# Nest.js @WebSocketGateway can not read .env variable

Tags: cors, environment-variables, nestjs

When I set the CORS options using the @WebSocketGateway decorator, it doesn't recognize the environmental variable.

```
Copy code
@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.ORIGIN,
    credentials: true,
  },
})
```

When I manually hardcode the ORIGIN, everything functions correctly. Interestingly, this setup worked in the past. The CORS error for WebSocket connections only started appearing at some point. Notably, the deployed version of my app is functioning without any issues.

I initially suspected that the environmental variable might be undefined. To confirm this, I checked its value within the onModuleInit() method and found that it is indeed defined.
I also tried to restart both client and server servers, however the error persists.